# Updating a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I need on coding to check a mysql DB to see if it needs to be updated.  The DB is for stock info & will only download the info if it is not currently in the DB.  I'm trying to figure how to design my code without making some long peice of coding that may be able to be done in a few lines of code.

I currently am using the information_schema UPDATE_TIME info for the table, so I have that info.  But where I'm stuck is how to I use php to check if the DB needs to be updated.

So in essence, I'm looking for a code snippet that will check to see if the table needs to be updated but will check for the duplicate info (i.e. if it makes it through an "if" statement & then downloads it anyway, if it is duplicate info, it will not insert it [I can use the date for this]).

Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear to me whether you're just trying to go a very roundabout way to do [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Think of this :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName" WHERE ConditionYouHave)
or die(mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('value1','value2','value3')"));
```

Comment: Remove `die()` or the script will stop after updating once.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some sort of datafeed you can run through to check for new data?  If this is the case I would go line-by-line through the file looking for new rows.  When you find one, you insert it into your table.  If the row already exists just continue on to the next row.  This can be done fairly simply in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, column2)
SELECT {$int_id}, '{$str_column2}'
FROM table_name
WHERE id = {$int_id} AND column2 != 'what ever you want'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column2 = VALUES(column2)
```

table_name is your own table's name.

I assumed you have a id column. And column2 is just an example.

You can validate your row through the WHERE and have whatever condition you wish.

Your [question's comment links](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to this example.